# How do I set a generic object in my array to 0/null?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, generics

I have an array that in my class declaration holds objects of generic type  (later on, I will add `<Integer>` type objects). I want to delete the index at currentSize (which is an int). Eclipse complains by saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert int to E" regarding to the line

`list[currentSize] = null;`

Here's my code:

```
...

private int currentSize, maxCapacity;

...

public ArrayABC(){
        currentSize = 0;
        maxCapacity = 20;
        list = (E[]) new Object[maxCapacity];
}

...

public E removeLast(){
        if(currentSize == 0)
            return null;

        list[currentSize] = null;
        currentSize--;
        return list[currentSize];
}
```

Also note that after I try to assign the list[currentSize] as a return value. Do I have to cast it to `<E>` while doing so (very last line of the code)?

I guess a better way of putting this is, how do I destroy the object at location = currentSize?

Thank you for your help and support in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use lists with generics instead of arrays?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do it this way

Comment: Can you post a compilable example? I.e. include the surrounding class and used attribute declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how your **list** is declared.
Also since you cast it to type parameter **E** you must use this type parameter somewhere in your class declaration like this: **`<E>`**

Below compiles for me just fine:

```
public class ArrayABC<E> {

  private int currentSize, maxCapacity;
  private E[] list;

  public ArrayABC(){
          currentSize = 0;
          maxCapacity = 20;
          list = (E[]) new Object[maxCapacity];
  }

  public E removeLast(){
          if(currentSize == 0)
              return null;
          list[currentSize] = null;
          currentSize--;
          return list[currentSize];
  }
}
```

The only snag is that Eclipse is highlighting:

```
list = (E[]) new Object[maxCapacity];
```

as warning with unsafe access, but there is no clean way to create instance of any object with type **E** due to type erasure.